# Javascript Rock Paper Scissors not working

Tags: javascript

I tried making rock paper scissors in JS. I wanted it to be so that it would count points and announce the winner. But my code is a mess. The computer always wins, always prints that you lose. I cant really make out what the issues are. I also tried to make it so that after every round, you can make a new choice, but that didnt really work out as planned either.

```js
var pcChoice = ["Steen", "Papier", "Schaar"];
var userChoice = prompt("Steen, papier of schaar?");
var pcWins = 0;
var userWins = 0;
var totalWins = pcWins + userWins
var win = ("Je hebt de ronde gewonnen!")
var Verlies = ("Je hebt verloren")

function randomNumber() {
  return (Math.floor(Math.random() * 3));
}

console.log("Computer koos: " + pcChoice[randomNumber()]);
console.log("Jij koos: " + userChoice);

if (pcWins + userWins === 2) {
  prompt("Nieuwe keuze")
}
if (pcWins + userWins === 1) {
  prompt("Nieuwe keuze")
}

while (pcWins + userWins < 3) {
  if (userChoice === pcChoice) {
    console.log("Gelijkspel");
  } else if (userChoice === "Steen" && pcChoice === "Schaar") {
    console.log(win) + userWins++
  } else if (userChoice === "Papier" && pcChoice === "Steen") {
    console.log(win) + userWins++
  } else if (userChoice === "Schaar" && pcChoice === "Papier") {
    console.log(win) + userWins++
  } else {
    console.log(Verlies) + pcWins++
  }
}

// Het volgende zal de winner uitprinten
if (pcWins > userWins) {
  console.log("De computer wint!")
} else {
  console.log("Je hebt gewonnen")
}
```

Comment: `pcChoice` is always the original array. Comparing it to strings is never going to be true.

Comment: Hey, thanks. sorry that my code is unclear and my question is bad. Where am i comparing pcChoice to a string?

Comment: Fix your if-else block. You are trying to compare a string to an array. pcChoice should be a string.

Comment: thank you. I get it now.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of typos and beginner mistakes.

I have cleaned your code in the snippet below.

**Always make sure your While loops don't loop indefinitely!**

```js
var pcChoices = [
    'Steen',
    'Papier',
    'Schaar'
];
var userChoice = prompt('Steen, papier of schaar?');
var pcWins = 0;
var userWins = 0;
var totalWins = pcWins + userWins;
var win = ('Je hebt de ronde gewonnen!');
var Verlies = ('Je hebt verloren');
function randomNumber() {
    return (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2));
}
console.log('Computer koos: ' + pcChoices[randomNumber()]);
console.log('Jij koos: ' + userChoice);
if (pcWins + userWins === 2) {
    prompt('Nieuwe keuze');
}
if (pcWins + userWins === 1) {
    prompt('Nieuwe keuze');
}
while (pcWins + userWins < 3) {
    var pcChoice = pcChoices[randomNumber()];
    if (userChoice === pcChoice) {
        console.log('Gelijkspel');
        break;
    }
    else if (userChoice === 'Steen' && pcChoice === 'Schaar') {
        console.log(win);
        userWins++;
    }
    else if (userChoice === 'Papier' && pcChoice === 'Steen') {
        console.log(win);
        userWins++;
    }
    else if (userChoice === 'Schaar' && pcChoice === 'Papier') {
        console.log(win);
        userWins++;
    }
    else {
        console.log(Verlies);
        pcWins++;
    }
} // Het volgende zal de winner uitprinten
if (pcWins > userWins) {
    console.log('De computer wint!');
}
else {
    console.log('Je hebt gewonnen');
}
```

Comment: Its still not completely flawless, but you really helped me out.

Comment: "Always remember to break your while loops!"... Hmmm... What?

Comment: @MerijnKruk Didn't help that it's in a language i don't speak :). Hope it's enough to get you moving, otherwise hit me back.

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen It's from an earlier version. It would keep iterating, even after it knew the winner.

Comment: I'm just not comfortable with the comment `ALWAYS remember to break your while loops!"... That is not the paradigm of a while loop... You break if you have to... you don't ALWAYS have to break...

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen Simplified speak. Always make sure your `While` loops don't loop indefinitely?

Comment: @EmilS.Jørgensen: Agreed. :)

Comment: Been looking into it, i changed my code abit but its still randomized AF it will randomly identify stone vs paper as a tie etc

Comment: Nvm, after trial and error ive been able to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps.
It takes things one round at a time rather than all at once.  The result or a round is calculated by looking up a little table.  There is no reason that your version of calculating a win would not work though.

Please forgive my Dutch.

```js
var choice = {STEEN: 0, PAPIER: 1, SCHAAR: 2};
var resultMatrix = [[0, -1, 1], [1, 0, -1], [-1, 1, 0]];

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function playRound(round){
  var userInput = prompt("Round " + round + ": steen, papier of schaar?");
  var userChoice = choice[userInput.toUpperCase()];

  var pcInput = Object.keys(choice)[getRandomInt(0,2)];
  var pcChoice = choice[pcInput];

  var result = resultMatrix[userChoice][pcChoice];

  console.log("Ronde " + round);
  console.log("Jij koos: " + userInput.toUpperCase());
  console.log("Computer koos: " + pcInput);
  
  switch(result){
      case -1:
        console.log("De computer wint!");
        break;
      case 0:
        console.log("Gelijkspel");
        break;
      case 1:
        console.log("Je hebt gewonnen");
        break;
  }

  console.log(" ");

  return result
};

var totalUserWins = 0;
for(var i=1; i<=3; i++){ totalUserWins += playRound(i); }

console.log("Laatste");
if (totalUserWins > 0) { console.log("Je hebt gewonnen"); } else
if (totalUserWins === 0) { console.log("Het is een gelijkspel"); } else
if (totalUserWins < 0) { console.log("De computer wint!"); }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply dude. Works like a train. It looks like a foreign language to me, but im trying to understand the best as i can.